# Avoiding memory leak in node js while using a leaking node module?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using node module @google-cloud/PubSub. One of its method to publish message is leaking memory.
Is there any hack to work around it by which we can still call this leaking function and avoid leak in our application ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to the issue reported at https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/1069. One recommendation from that thread is to reuse the same PubSub client across multiple requests.

Comment: This advice helped me fix a memory leak I had when launching **Google Tasks** from a **Firebase Cloud function**. Seems like it's always better to define a global client with this kind of Google Cloud services